# Passing results from find to function

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
my_variable=100
format () {
    echo $0 ##result of find
    echo $1 ##my_variable
}
export -f format 
find . -type f -exec bash -c format {} \;
```

Is there a way I can pass `my_variable` to function call in find command?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply pass `my_variable` as an additional argument to the shell the runs `format`. (Note that `$0` is not the first argument to the function.)

```
#!/bin/bash
my_variable=100
format () {
    echo $1  # result of find
    echo $2  # my_variable
}
export -f format 
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'format "$1" "$2"' bash {} "$my_variable" \;
```

The dummy argument `bash` is used to set `$0` in the command, so that `{}` is the first positional argument to be passed to `format`.

To reduce the number of times you need to run `bash`, you can use the `-exec ... +` form:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'v=$1; shift; for f; do format "$f" "$v"; done' \
   bash "$my_variable" {} +
```

This passes multiple files to the shell at once; the script is responsible for extracting `my_variable` from the argument list first, then iterating over the rest, calling `format` once per file.